# How to write a dataweave expression for given input and output

Tags: dataweave

I am trying to convert the Salesforce response into a JSON array

Input:

`[`
`{`
`"Name": "SubscriberKey",`
`"Value": "38hgf5"`
`},`
`{`
`"Name": "EmailAddress",`
`"Value": "xyz@aol.com"`
`}`
`],`
`[`
`{`
`"Name": "SubscriberKey",`
`"Value": "54889"`
`},`
`{`
`"Name": "EmailAddress",`
`"Value": "abc@aol.com"`
`}`
`]`

Desired Output:

`[ { "SubscriberKey": "38hgf5", "EmailAddress": "xyz@aol.com" }, { "SubscriberKey": "54889", "EmailAddress": "abc@aol.com" } ]`

I have tried below code

dw 2.0

`payload map (item, index) -> {`
`"SubscriberKey" : item.Value ,`
`"EmailAddress" : item.Value`
`` }` ``

but it is producing below output.

`[`
`{`
`"SubscriberKey": "38hgf5",`
`"EmailAddress": "38hgf5"`
`},`
`{`
`"SubscriberKey": "xyz@aol.com",`
`"EmailAddress": "xyz@aol.com"`
`}`
`]`

I have also tried adding filter, if else condition and using the reduce function.

Comment: For blocks of code you should use the code format triple backtick (`\`\`\``) instead of single bacticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the input is an array of arrays where each record has a name and a value:

```json
[
    [
        {
            "Name": "SubscriberKey",
            "Value": "38hgf5"
        },
        {
            "Name": "EmailAddress",
            "Value": "xyz@aol.com"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Name": "SubscriberKey",
            "Value": "54889"
        },
        {
            "Name": "EmailAddress",
            "Value": "abc@aol.com"
        }
    ]
]
```

So to obtain the output you need to map each child array using reduce to get each item name and value and concatenate them as key-value pairs into objects with the form that you need:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map ($ reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ {(item.Name): item.Value }))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "SubscriberKey": "38hgf5",
    "EmailAddress": "xyz@aol.com"
  },
  {
    "SubscriberKey": "54889",
    "EmailAddress": "abc@aol.com"
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, the input is an array of arrays. Your solution works perfect. Thanks @aled.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your input payload is not a proper json. I hope you are using foreach for the salesforce response and them use the below dataweave script.
Let me know if this helps.
Input:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "SubscriberKey",
    "Value": "38hgf5"
  },
  {
    "Name": "EmailAddress",
    "Value": "xyz@aol.com"
  }
]
```

Dataweave script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload reduce ((item, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ {(item.Name): item.Value})
```

Output:

```
{
  "SubscriberKey": "38hgf5",
  "EmailAddress": "xyz@aol.com"
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct for a single array but it will fail with multiple elements. I'm realizing that my answer is the same but just adds a map for that case.

Comment: This solution also works with a For Each loop. Thanks @Harsha

Answer (score 1):

The input format isn't correct. If you have nested arrays like below input, this could be a solution:

Input:

```
[
  [
    {
      "Name": "SubscriberKey",
      "Value": "38hgf5"
    },
    {
      "Name": "EmailAddress",
      "Value": "xyz@aol.com"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Name": "SubscriberKey",
      "Value": "54889"
    },
    {
      "Name": "EmailAddress",
      "Value": "abc@aol.com"
    }
  ]
]
```

DW:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
payload flatMap (item, index) -> {
  (item map {
    ($.Name): ($.Value)
  })
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "SubscriberKey": "38hgf5",
    "EmailAddress": "xyz@aol.com"
  },
  {
    "SubscriberKey": "54889",
    "EmailAddress": "abc@aol.com"
  }
]
```